# как можно печатать неравные элементы строки, и без колекции

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "aabbccd";
    String s2 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j=1;j<s1.length();j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(j)) {
                s2 += s1.charAt(i);
            }

        }

    }
    System.out.println(s2);

}
```

}

Comment: Вопрос, которого тут нет, не ясен

Comment: Что не ясно ????

Comment: собственно всё: что это, что такое "неравные элементы строки", куда печатать. не стесняйся, выражай мысли яснее и четче

Comment: Есть куда кроме System.out?

Comment: Может, когда элемент не равен предыдущему?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka в `out` обычно не печатают, а совершают другое действие. В ином случае под "печатать" можно подразумевать и `File.Write` и `socket.write` и просто принтер

Comment: нужно вытащить из строки те элементы которые не повтаряютсяа , к примеру есть 21123 пусть выдаст 3

Comment: Тогда нужно проверять на сравнение со всеми, и делать выход по break по первому совпадению

Comment: Спасибо Hasmik )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вот один из возможных ответов:

```
class answ1 {
        static String getNotEq(final String text) {
            String in = text;
            final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                    String symbol = String.valueOf(in.charAt(0));
                    out.append(symbol);
                    in = in.replace(symbol, "");
            }

            return out.toString();
        }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
            System.out.println(getNotEq("A***h3%yr9ug%kfJA31JAb"));
    }
}
```

---

```
Вывод: A*h3%yr9ugkfJ1b
```

Или так, чтобы вывести только те символы, которые не повторяются:

```
class answ1 {
    static String getNotEq(final String text) {
            String in = text;
            final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                    char symbol = in.charAt(0);
                    if (in.indexOf(symbol) == in.lastIndexOf(symbol)) out.append(symbol);
                    in = in.replace(String.valueOf(symbol), "");
            }

            return out.toString();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
            System.out.println(getNotEq("A***h3%yr9ug%kfJA31JAb"));
    }
}
```

---

```
Вывод: hyr9ugkf1b
```